# How do you get Hibernate to update database statistics?

Tags: hibernate, h2, table-statistics

I am putting a lot of rows into a database table that was previously nearly empty, Im then creating a report based on data in that table. Although the table is indexed the queries are taking far too long and Im guessing it is because Hibernate is doing a full table scan every time for the query instead of using the indexes because it believes the database table to only contain a couple of rows.

How do I make Hibernate update database statistics for the table so it can then construct a suitable query plan ?

Comment: I assume you can create a stored procedure that you invoke using the [native sql option](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13646) hibernate provides.

Comment: @rene I dont see where stored procedures come in, must be a simpler way

Comment: Recent version of H2 do automatically update the statistics, so you don't need to do that manually. In many cases the problem is that the query doesn't benefit from any index. I suggest to analyze which queries are really slow, and then check why the index is not used for those (using `explain select` or `explain analyze select`).

Comment: @Thomas Mueller ,okay I guessed they did update the stats but when, Im sure they dont do it after every query. I know how to explain an SQL query but is there a hibernate call I can do to make it show me the queryplan it is using when doing a hibernate query ?

Comment: The statistics don't need to be updated very frequently. In all cases I know, the automatic update is sufficient. Hibernate doesn't know `explain select` as far as I'm aware, so you would need to call it manually (for example using the H2 Console). But you can enable better logging on Hibernate so you see what SQL statements are executed (and possibly, which statements are slow).

Comment: No they don't have to be updated regulary but if the amount of data in the table has been dramatically increased I would hope the statistics are updated before next query of table, but Id prefer to not just hope. I know the query that is being sent but I dont know how the query is being performed.

Comment: Hibernate is not the one which computes the query plan. It simply translates HQL to SQL, and sends the SQL to the database, which computes the query plan. You should configure the database, and not Hibernate, to recompute the statistics. Moreover, don't guess what is happening. Execute the SQL query Hibernate is using through an explain plan, and see what the computed plan is.

Comment: But I still don't understand when the statistics are updated, does hibernate make a call to analyze ever so often. Or is the database itself itself that decides to run analyze sometimes. Or is it never actually run unless I explicity do it myself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate can run [native SQL statements](http://dev-answers.blogspot.ch/2012/04/running-native-sql-deletes-or-updates.html), this way you can also run [`analyze`](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#analyze):

```
Query analyze = session.createSQLQuery("analyze");
analyze.executeUpdate();
```

See also the official documentation about [native SQL statement execution](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html).

Comment: Thanks, But I still don't understand when the statistics are updated, does hibernate make a call to analyze ever so often. Or is the database itself itself that decides to run analyze sometimes. Or is it never actually run unless I explicity do it myself as you suggest ?

Comment: Hibernate doesn't call it, but the database itself does it (it maintains a counter for each table, and if there were many changes in a table then the statistics are updated). As I wrote in the comment above: "Recent version of H2 do automatically update the statistics, so you don't need to do that manually."